# Python : How to stay logged in while scraping?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

Just to clarify from the beginning: I'm a total beginner (I wrote something in Python for the first time today). This was more applying from a guide and trying to remember what I did 7 years ago when I tried learning java than anything else.
I wanted to scrape the image tags from a website (to plot them later) but have to stay logged in to view all images. After I got the scraping down I noticed that there were some tags blocked so the issue with the login came up. I now managed to log in but it doesn't work outside of the session itself which makes the rest of my code useless. Can I get this to work or do I have to give up?
This is the working login:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

login_data = {
    'user' : 'theusername',
    'pass' : 'thepassword',
    'op' : 'Log in'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://thatwebsite.com/index.php?page=account&s=login&code=00"
    r = s.get(url)
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data)
```

And what I had working before to scrape the website but with the login missing:

```
filename = "taglist.txt"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")
headers = "tags\n"
f.write(headers)

pid = 0
actual_page = 1
while pid < 150:
    url = "https://thatwebsite.com/index.php?page=post&s=list&tags=absurdres&pid=" + str(pid)
    print(url)
    client = urlopen(url)
    page_html = client.read()
    client.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"thumbnail-preview"})
    print("Current pid: " + str(pid))
    for container in containers:
        tags = container.span.a.img["title"]

        f.write(tags.replace(" ", "\n") + "\n")

    pid = pid + 42
    print("Current page: " + str(actual_page))
    actual_page += 1
    print("Done.")

f.close()
```

Out comes a list of every tag used by high res images. 
I hope I don't offend anyone with this.

**Edit:** The code is working now, had a cookie typo:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

login_data = {
    'user' : 'myusername',
    'pass' : 'mypassword',
    'op' : 'Log in'
}

s = requests.Session()    

print("\n\n\n\n\n")

filename = "taglist.txt"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")
headers = "tags\n"
f.write(headers)

pid = 0
actual_page = 1
while pid < 42:

    url2 = "https://thiswebsite.com/index.php?page=post&s=list&tags=rating:questionable&pid=" + str(pid)
    r = s.get(url2, cookies={'duid' : 'somehash', 'user_id' : 'my userid', 'pass_hash' : 'somehash'})
    page_html = str(r.content)
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"thumbnail-preview"})
    for container in containers:
        tags = container.span.a.img["title"]
        f.write(tags.replace(" ", "\n") + "\n")


    print("\nCurrent page: " + str(actual_page) + " Current pid: " + str(pid) + "\nDone.")
    actual_page += 1
    pid = pid + 42

f.close()
```

Comment: It helps to break up your question into specific discrete issues; For instance, After I login X happens instead of Y.

Answer (score 0):

You use two different libraries for doing web requests right now. `requests` and `urllib`. I would opt for using only requests.

Also don't use the Session() **context manager**. Context manager are used to do some cleanup after leaving the indented block and have that `with ... as x` syntax you use on the requests.Session() object. In context of requests this will clear the cookies as you leave the session. (I assume login is managed by cookies at this site).

Keep the session in a variable instead that you can use for subsequent requests as this stores your cookies at login. You need them for subsequent requests.

```
s = requests.Session() 
url = "https://thatwebsite.com/index.php?page=account&s=login&code=00"
r = s.get(url)  # do you need this request?
r = s.post(url, data=login_data)
```

Also make the subsequent call in the loop with requests:

```
client = s.get(url)
```